# i want to change the color in my objective c headers. creating a tweak for ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hello I'm learning to develop tweaks for ios. I downloaded an opensource tweak and I first wanted to change the colors. I changed them all but one I can't find out how. I want to make the title for headers white and in the center and bigger text

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)table titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return @"Border Size";
        case 1:
            return @"Border Color";
        case 2:
            return @"Badge Tint Alpha";
        default:
            return nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`titleForHeaderInSection` can only return a string , you need to implement

```
 NSArray*arr ;
 NSArray*colors;
```

---

In `viewDidLoad`

```
arr = [@"Border Size",@"Border Color",@"Badge Tint Alpha"];
colors = [[UIColor redColor],[UIColor blueColor],[UIColor greenColor]];
```

---

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
   UILabel*lbl = [UILabel new];
   lbl.text = arr[section];
   lbl.backgroundColor = colors[section];
   return lbl;
}
```

Comment: Im tottaly new to this how do i implement  NSArray*arr ; and  NSArray*colors;?

Comment: You declare arr and colors as NSArray in header file. Then you put the two lines in viewDidLoad.